# Why is it that the number of nucleon in an element is the mass of the element

Tags: mass-spectrometry

Why is it that the number of nucleon in an element is the mass of the element for example the mass of oxygen is 32g and the nucleon number is 32.

Comment: Roughly speaking, because proton weighs 1, neutron weighs 1, and electron weighs nothing. Also, it is 16, not 32.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Ivan Neretin, the reason that the mass of an atom (in atomic mass units or amu) corresponds to the number of nucleons (hence the name mass number for this quantity) is that the mass of the proton and neutron are roughly 1 amu and the mass of the electron is negligible. The fact that the mass of the atom in amu corresponds to the molar mass in g/mol is a consequence of the definition of the number of particles in one mole. The conversion factor for amu to g is $1.660539\times10^{-24}$ g/amu this is equal to the reciprocal of Avogadro's number (this is how much mole one single particle represent) $1/N_\text{A}=1/6.0221409\times 10^{23}=1.660539\times10^{-24}$ mol. Because these factors are equal the atomic mass corresponds to the molar mass.

Note that the deviations of the real mass to the mass number are larger for the heavier elements because the number of electrons increases and also the binding energy per nucleon increases (the so-called mass defect). Note also that the masses in the periodic table often represent the mass averaged over the natural isotopes.